# Show data in a html expandable table from Json data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to work with the HTML table in the MVC application. Actually, my HTML rows are expandable, I am able to insert JSON response data in the table but I am having trouble inserting data in expanding rows.I need to do that when I am clicking on the Refresh button.

Here is my model class which includes Model Class and Company

```
 public class Project
    {
        public int Idx { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public bool Action { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    }

public class Company
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public decimal Completed { get; set; }
        public float Task { get; set; }
        public Datetime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my code in Controller from which I am getting data to show in html table

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Refresh()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Project> project = new List<Project>();
                project = _context.Project.toList();
                foreach(var item in Company)
                {
                project.Companies = _context.Company.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 
                item.CompanyId).Tolist();
                return Json(project)
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

This is code that I have in View including Javascript

```
<div>
<table id="projectModel>
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>CompanyId</th>
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Project.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.Project.[i].Companies)
                                    {
                                        <th data-hide="all">CompanyName</th>
                                        <th data-hide="all">Completed</th>
                                        <th data-hide="all">Task</th>
                                        <th data-hide="all">Date</th>
                                    }
                                }
                                </tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Project.Count; i++)
                            {
                            <tr>
                                <td data-filter="#filter">@Model.Project.[i].Idx</td>
                                <td>@Model.Project.[i].Project </td>
                                <td>@Model.Project.[i].Name</td>
                                <td>@Model.Project.[i].Phone</td>
                                <td>@Model.Project.[i].Action</td>
                                <td>@Model.Project.[i].CompanyId</td>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Project.[i].Companies)
                                {
                                    <td>@item.CompanyId</td>
                                    <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
                                    <td>@item.Completed</td>
                                    <td>@item.Task</td>
                                    <td>@item.Date</td>
                                }

                            </tr>
                            }
  </tbody>
</table>
 <button type="button" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
</div

<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh() {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: '@Url.Action("Refresh", "Home")',
                                dataType: "json",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                success: function (response) {
                                    var trHTML = '';
                                    debugger;
                                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                                        if (i < 15) {
                                            trHTML += '<tr class="footable-even"><td data-filter="#filter" class="footable-visible footable-first-column"><span class="footable-toggle"></span>' + item.Idx + '</td><td class="footable-visible">' + item.Project + '</td><td class="footable-visible">' + item.Name + '</td><td class="footable-visible">' + item.Phone + '</td><td class="footable-visible">' + item.Action + '</td></tr>';
                         
                                           
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $('#projectModel tbody').html(trHTML);

                                },
                                error: function (error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                }
                            });
 </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Please define trouble

Comment: Hi Vivek , I want to how can I  insert JSON data into child rows using Jquery